# What is the proper Japanese word for the germ theory of disease?

Tags: word-requests

I was looking for a Japanese word for [the germ theory of disease](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Germ_theory_of_disease). I found [an article in the Japanese Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/ja/%E7%97%85%E5%8E%9F%E4%BD%93#/.E7.B4.B0.E8.8F.8C.E8.AA.AC.E3.81.A8.E7.92.B0.E5.A2.83.E8.AA.AC) that uses the word 細菌説{さいきんせつ} for what essentially is the germ theory. Is it the correct word or there is some other alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

「細菌説」 seems to be a fair choice, but there are alternatives. Here's what I gathered:

- 「細菌説」

  - *English-Japanese medical dictionary*<sup>[1]</sup>
  - *Encyclopedia of pharmaceutical history*<sup>[2]</sup>, in describing Pasteur.
- 「（疾患）病原菌論」

  - *Japan medical terminology*<sup>[3]</sup> from the Japanese Association of Medical Sciences.
- 「微生物起因説」

  - *Igaku-Shoin's medical dictionary*<sup>[4]</sup>,  in the article of Pasteur
- 「微生物説」

  - *医科細菌学*[5] (medical bacteriology)
- 「媒菌説]

  - *An English-Japanese dictionary of medical science*<sup>[6]</sup>

Note that,  although the *germ theory* is often referred to as the *細菌説*， *細菌* does not really correspond to *germ*.

As far as understand, *germ* in this context is basically an informal synonym of *pathogen* == something that causes disease. This corresponds to 病原体, while 細菌 is more specific word for bacteria. Related terms include

- 微生物 (micro-living) : microbes.
- 病原体 (illness-source/cause-thing) : Sounds formal and technical. germ / pathogen.
- ばい菌 : informal, non-technical, plain word for "those living things that reproduce and cause illness" or "that thing you want to remove by washing hands to avoid desease". Probably closest to *germ*.
- 細菌 : bacteria. (Although sometimes misused for much broader sense)
- 菌 : very vague word for fungi (not in the context of cuisine) + bacteria + yeast + etc.

---

1: "[医学用語大辞典](http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I000002046090-00)". 日外アソシエーツ, 1989.

2: "[薬学史事典](http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I027211872-00)".      日本薬史学会 編. 薬事日報社, 2016.

3: "[日本医学会医学用語辞典](http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I000008502728-00)". 南山堂, 2007.

4: ["医学書院医学大辞典"](http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I000010048126-00). 医学書院, 2009.

5: ["医科細菌学"](http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I000009412256-00). 笹川 千尋. 南江堂, 2008.

6:  ["医学英和辞典"](http://iss.ndl.go.jp/books/R100000002-I000003661775-00). 研究社, 2009.

Comment: Thank you so much for such an elaborate answer. I especially appreciate your list of related words with explanations.